# Spinner with image and text

Tags: android, android-spinner

I want my spinner to look like this [image]

Only the topmost header should have image and text. Remaining drop down should have text only.
Can anyone help me in making this.

**I have tried this..**

I my xml file

```
 <Spinner android:id="@+id/spinner1"
 android:layout_width="200dp"
 android:layout_height="50dp"
 android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
 android:layout_below="@id/view" 
android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
 android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
 android:background="@drawable/grey_btn"
 android:popupBackground="@drawable/drop_down_background"
 android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />
```

and then

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(mContext, R.drawable.spinner_text,R.id.customtextview,arr1); adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(R.drawable.drop_down); s1.setAdapter(adapter1);
```

Comment: <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/view"
        android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/grey_btn"
        android:popupBackground="@drawable/drop_down_background"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />

Comment: ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(mContext, R.drawable.spinner_text,R.id.customtextview,arr1);      
     adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(R.drawable.drop_down);
     s1.setAdapter(adapter1);

Comment: @ASP nopes this will set the image to drop down item i want it for header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have both a getView and getDropDownView in the adapter. In that way you could specify different looks on the selected item and the rest of the list.

in getView:

```
textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.spinner_item_text);
imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.spinner_item_image);
textView.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
imageView.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
```

in getDropDownView:

```
textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.spinner_item_text);
imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.spinner_item_image);
textView.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
imageView.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
```